# How can I load a .txt file into JS with Parcel?

Tags: javascript, txt, parceljs

I'm trying to load an autogenerated (format is out of my control) `data.txt` file containing a number of 1 line quotes. I want to avoid preprocessing (ex making a script that turns the `.txt` file into a `.json` file) and import the txt file directly into my script code.

```js
// @parcel/core: No transformers found for data.txt.
import data from "./data.txt"

const lines = data.split("\n")

for (const line of lines) {
    const spanElement = document.createElement("span")
    // ...set span element content and append to DIV
}
```

And yes, I've tried [bundle inlining](https://parceljs.org/features/bundle-inlining/), but that's for bundles.

My main use case is to use this to make HTML elements to style like so:

```html
<div class="quotes">
    <p>{a quote line}</p>
</div>
```

So I'm looking for how to import a `txt` file as a string into JS and turn it into DOM elements to add to my `.quotes` element. If there's a better way that I can load it in so I can avoid [Client Side Rendering](https://web.dev/rendering-on-the-web/) that would also be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bundle-text:`

```
import data from "bundle-text:./data.txt" // works!

const lines = data.split("\n")

for (const line of lines) {
    const spanElement = document.createElement("span")
    // ...set span element content and append to DIV
}
```